# Using HTML and CSS for a Java GUI

Tags: java, css, html, user-interface

This is for an offline application. However, I would like the front end to be run in a web browser. What I want is, a simple gui design in HTML/CSS. I want to be able to execute java commands at a button's press. Furthermore, I would like to be able to display and read information from the browser. Is this feasible?

Comment: I can't decide if this question is too broad or doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [JxBrowser](https://www.teamdev.com/jxbrowser). [The knowledge base](https://jxbrowser.support.teamdev.com/support/solutions) contains some pretty good example. Unfortunately, it is not free though.